# Why I can declare a const reference using type-alias?

Tags: c++, reference

I have a simple question: As I know I can declare a `const` pointer to some datatype or a pointer to constant datatype but I can only declare a reference to a constant datatype only and no constant reference to a datatype; the fact that a reference is already constant because it cannot be rebound to another object.

So when I try to create a `const ref to someDataType` I get compile-time error. But the thing that matters me is when used with `type alias` using `typedef` or `using`. e.g:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    int i{ 10 };
    //  int& const r1{ i }; // error: ‘const’ qualifiers cannot be applied to ‘int&’. Ok here.
    using rInt = int&; // or typedef int& rInt;
    const rInt r2{ i }; // why const is allowed here?
    ++r2; // this proves that the const is applied to the reference not to the object referred to.

    std::cout << r2 << std::endl; // 11

}
```

As you can see above I can add `const` to the reference which I think is Redundant in that context. But why C++ allows this with type-aliases but not directly?

Comment: On my compiler, I got `Alex24.cpp:8:5: warning: 'const' qualifier on reference type 'rInt' (aka 'int &') has no effect [-Wignored-qualifiers]` ... do you have warnings turned on?  I presume this is irrelevant to your question, as you are asking WHY is const allowed (even if ignored).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Why I can change the object through `rInt` then?

Comment: @Alex24 I was mistaken and already deleted my comment.

Comment: @Eljay: Are you using VC++14?

Comment: "But why C++ allows this with type-aliases but not directly?" first and foremost the fact that a compiler accepts it does not mean C++ allows it.

Comment: It is the same as `using t_Value = int const; t_Value const value{};`, applying `const` second time has no effect. However your reference is a reference to mutable object therefore you can change the object using that reference. Note that adding `const` to `rInt` does not convert reference into to a reference to const-qualified object.

Comment: I'm using `clang++` with `-std=c++17`.

Comment: @Alex24 *"But why C++ allows this with type-aliases but not directly?"* I'm not convinced that the language formally forbids it. Edit : For what it's worth `r1` produces a warning in VC++ 14.0.

Comment: You might want to add `language-lawyer` tag, as I assume you want chapter+verse from the standard.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because the standard say so:

> [dcl.ref] ... Cv-qualified references are ill-formed except when the cv-qualifiers are introduced through the use of a typedef-name ([dcl.typedef], [temp.param]) or decltype-specifier ([dcl.type.simple]), in which case the cv-qualifiers are ignored

This is similar to how you cannot declare a reference reference, while it is possible through a typedef (where the references collapse into one):

```
int i;
int& iref = i;
//int& & irefref = iref; // not OK
using Iref = int&;
Iref& iretypedef = iref; // OK; collapses into int&
```

The CV-collapsing rules, just like reference collapsing rules are essential to make templates and type deductions usable.

Answer (score 5):

This is a case where common sense comes into play.  Since references cannot be reassigned they act as if they were `const`.  Adding `const` to a reference declaration doesn't add anything and as such `T & const` is forbidder per [[dcl.ref]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.ref#1)

> [...]  Cv-qualified references are ill-formed except when the cv-qualifiers are introduced through the use of a typedef-name ([dcl.typedef], [temp.param]) or decltype-specifier ([dcl.type.simple]), in which case the cv-qualifiers are ignored.

You'll notice though that it is allowed then the reference is a *typedef-name* or *decltype-specifier*. So if `T` is `T&` then the `const` is ignored.  If it wasn't it would make generic programming harder.

Comment: There's no such thing as "implicitly `const`" , and references are not `const`.  Try `std::is_const_v<int&>`

Comment: They don't act as if they were `const` either. If you try to assign to a const object you get an error. The language doesn't even allow the attempt to reassign a reference.